# Why is my little STRef Int require allocating gigabytes?

Tags: haskell, optimization

```
3,200,056,496 bytes allocated in the heap
```

Wut? This is a small test for STRef:

```
bigNumber =
    runST $ do
        ref <- newSTRef (0 :: Int)
        replicateM_ 100000000 $ modifySTRef' ref (+1)
        readSTRef ref
```

`modifySTRef'` is strict. `STRef` is supposed to operate directly on memory so I don't see the need for lots of allocations.

Here's the full code:

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad
import Data.STRef

bigNumber :: Int
bigNumber =
    runST $ do
        ref <- newSTRef (0 :: Int)
        replicateM_ 100000000 $ modifySTRef' ref (+1)
        readSTRef ref

main :: IO ()
main = print bigNumber
```

Build for profiling like:

```
ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp tryST.hs
```

Run like:

```
./tryST +RTS -pa -sstderr
```

Highlight from `tryST.prof`

```
 bigNumber    Main  95 1   95.7  100.0    95.7  100.0   1357 1600000032
```

The RTS report:

```
3,200,056,496 bytes allocated in the heap
      360,624 bytes copied during GC
        46,040 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
        23,592 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                  Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      6102 colls,     0 par    0.03s    0.03s     0.0000s    0.0002s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0007s    0.0013s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    1.33s  (  1.38s elapsed)
GC      time    0.03s  (  0.04s elapsed)
RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    1.35s  (  1.42s elapsed)

%GC     time       1.9%  (2.5% elapsed)

Alloc rate    2,413,129,982 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  98.1% of total user, 93.6% of total elapsed
```

This program isn't as fast as I'd like but the productivity is 98%. Great. Maximum residency 46k. Cool. But what is with all that allocation?

Answer (score 10):

The `Int` type is a box integer representation. When `(+1)` acts on the contents
of the `STRef`, a new heap object is created. Internally, the `STRef` holds a pointer to the heap object, and writes to that `STRef` modify the pointer, rather than updating an integer field. As you can see, doing this 1,000,000,000 times can result in a large number of Int objects being created, churning through a lot of memory.

Fortunately, these objects are not long lived, which is why relatively few bytes
are copied by the garbage collector. Indeed, this program is spending only a modest amount of time performing GC. Short lived objects like this are quite common in Haskell (and many other functional programming languages), and the garbage collector is designed to handle this efficiently.

Comment: Interesting. I was just learning about the benefits of unboxing today in the context of unboxed vectors. Is there a way to have an unboxed Int in the STRef?

Comment: @MichaelFox [This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ArrayRef-0.1.3.1/docs/Data-Ref-Unboxed.html) is one possible solution. I don't know if there is a standardized solution, however. I suppose you could use an unboxed vector of length 1, if you were desperate.

Comment: It ends up not being as important in practice. You don't put frequently-used values in a Ref type, you pass them around. If your code and the type of the value allow it, the value will be unboxed.

Comment: @sabauma I couldn't get ArrayRef to compile on a modern GHC, but the idea is sound. I reimplemented the above program using an unboxed `Vector` and it allocated 51kb total on the heap. See: http://lpaste.net/115549

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman That's definitely an improvement. In hindsight, I probably should have done something like that rather than throwing out speculation.

Comment: @sabauma I got inspired to create this repo as a result of this, in case it's useful: https://github.com/snoyberg/snoy-extra

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman This is extremely valuable for learning. I've yet to encounter any material on `PrimMonad`, `State#`. The run-time performance of my example is 3x slower than comparable C `for(i=0;i<100000000;i++);` and your example matches C. Interesting: `cc -O2` will remove the useless for loop and replace it with `i=100000000;`. `ghc -fllvm -O2` will do this to your `bigNumber` as well. May not be useful, but it's so cool. People should know.

Comment: That's definitely an area of the ecosystem that should be more well documented, I learnt it just by banging my head against the vector and primitive packages. I'll write it down as a "good to document" topic.